# How to identify the specific font file that my browser used to render an element?

Tags: browser, fonts, html

Is it possible to identify the specific font file that my browser used to render the text in an element?

The back story is that a web page (from a Chrome extension) renders an element using this style (found via dev tools)

```
{
    font-size: 22px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: 200;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

and looked terrible in the light thin rendering of Helvetica, as I didn't have Helvetica Neue installed. I tried to resolve this by installing a collection of 50+ font files, both *.ttf and *.otf that implement different forms of Helvetica Neue. One of these files fixed this instance but others have resulted in other pages looking horrible.

So I'm trying to identify which specific font file fixes the single case I had the original problem with so I can delete the others, but with so many font files this is awkward. Hence my question; is there any way to identify the font file used? This is on Windows 10 and 11, if that has any bearing. I can simulate the element in a simple HTML file using the same style and displaying in either Chrome or Edge, so the fact that the actual page is from a Chrome Extension is not relevant to the question. If I remove all the otf files the text looks bad so it is one of them that fixes the display, but which one?

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome Developer Tools provide all the information you want, down to the glyph!

For example, let’s take the Font Awesome “house” icon [here](https://fontawesome.com/search?f=classic&s=light):

[image: Font Awesome "house"]

If we take a look in Chrome’s Developer Tools (which you can bring up using <kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> or the hamburger menu → More tools → Developer tools) at the `<i>` element’s `::before` pseude element (where Font Awesome *font* icons are located), we’ll see the following:

[image: Chrome Developer Tools Computed style tab]

From the “Computed” style tab, we can see which fonts exactly where used to render the text in this element. In this case, one glyph from “Font Aweseome 6 Pro Light” was used to render the house icon.

There is a small caveat: This information only shows up for an element that directly contains text. You can’t select an entire document and see all fonts used inside. You’ll have to select the specific element that has the *text node*.

Using this information, you can even see which fonts were *substituted* in if the specified font was missing glyphs.

Comment: Thanks for this but it only partly answers the question. Given the style in my question, following your directions I get "Helvetica Neue — Local file (8 glyphs)" but I already knew that the style resulted in Helvetica Neue being used. What I really want to know, is which one of the 51 installed TTF and OTF files is the one used to render this particular size and weight of Helvetica Neue. In hindsight this may not be a function of the browser but of an operating system service.

Comment: The browser (or any application, really) is the only reliable source of truth for what is rendered. Other than the information I present here, nothing is available. I suggest you perform a ”binary search” on the font set to determine which one helps. This means you’ll only have to do _log(n)_ operations to narrow down the candidate list.

Comment: I took a different route; deleted all the Helvetica Neue font files and let it render in Arial. It's not quite as nice looking, but not ugly and weird looking like Helvetica was (got rid of that a while back). The bonus is that I no longer have other pages rendering in strange ways.l